# Function to require_once or include in PHP

Tags: php, function

I did some research, but since I couldn't find anything definitive, I'm asking here as a question now. If any of you know, I'm waiting for support..

I'm working on my own web software in PHP.

However, some pages consistently `require_once();` I need to include it in my pages along with.

The question I want to ask is:

for require_once() or include(); For functions, I want to set a custom function.
For example: I'm currently pulling a file to a different page and using it like this: `require_once(".../.../home/header.php");`

I wrote a custom function out of this technique, for example: `stack_overflow_template("home/header.php");` I want to include it as a page.

**In short, no matter what directory and how many folders I am behind, the function we will install will always see the home directory and stack_overflow_template(); We will be able to include pages easily with the function.**

How do I write a function like this? Can you help?

Comment: Is header.php just outputting HTML to the screen or does it contain functions that will be used? If it includes functions to be used, why can't you use require or include?

Comment: Using the require or include function makes me tired, my friend. When I need to pull a page from the content of a file that is constantly 2 or 3 folders behind (.../.../.../path/). I'm looking for a special function to avoid this.

Comment: @imvain2 Since I don't want to use require or include function, stack_overflow_template("home/header.php"); I want to execute a command like this.. Do you have any information on how to do it?

Comment: rethink your design pattern, if you use mvc approach then typically you have a template layout and you pass data to it then you don't need to include/require files in every new page you make

Comment: Useful reading: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths